# How to use systemd special units

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, i3, systemd-timer

I was trying to create a simple(ish) way to detect whether my laptop lid was closed and activate i3lock when it is. I know that this can be done through acpid or other methods, but I wanted to learn more about systemd timers anyway, so I went that way. It turns out that systemd has [special units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html) for timers, and one of them is for sleep, but I was unable to find anything online telling me how to do this, even on the usually amazing arch wiki. Does anyone know how to set up a service/timer to activate on these special units?

Comment: It's a target, so you would use it in, for example, a `Requires=` or `After=` declaration in your service file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sleep.target` is a target, so you name it in a `WantedBy` setting in your service unit file, and then enable the service.

## Further reading

- "[Sleep hooks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Sleep_hooks)". *Power management*.  Arch wiki.